# using Regular Expressions in PHP to return part of a string

Tags: regex, string, substring

I'm trying to retrieve only the version number out of a string, but the strings aren't formatted in a specific. For example, the strings may be written in (but not limited to) any of the following formats

- "Angry Birds v2.0.0"
- "Angry Birds 2.0.0"
- "v1.25"
- "Version: 1.3"
- "  2.0.1 "

I need to create a php function that will return ONLY the version number (ex: "2.0.0" from each of these strings. **Would using regular expressions be useful at all in this task?** If so, **what built in PCRE (perl compatible regular expressions) PHP functions should I make use of**?

Please keep in mind I have very little understanding of regular expressions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function GetVersion($string)
{
    if (preg_match("#(\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)*)#", $string, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    }
}

$test_strings = array(
    "Angry Birds v2.0.0",
    "Angry Birds 2.0.0",
    "v1.25",
    "Version: 1.3",
    " 2.0.1 ",
    "Dots4You v3.15"
);

foreach ($test_strings as $string) {
    printf("%s<br>", GetVersion($string));
}
```

RESULT:

> 2.0.0
>
> 2.0.0
>
> 1.25
>
> 1.3
>
> 2.0.1
>
> 3.15

@Tim Pietzcker:

Your code will fail when project's name alone will contain a digit, for example "Dots4You v3.15" will catch "4" as a version. Version should contain at least 2 digits and 1 dot.

Comment: Your version is a) inelegant (DRY!) and b) also has a bug: Try `UltraEdit 17.30.0.1002` (actual version number).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job that regexes are well suited for.

For example:

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(?:\.\d+)*/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\d+  # Match one or more digits
(?:  # Try to match...
 \.  # a dot
 \d+ # and one or more digits...
)*   # zero or more times.
```

This also matches single version numbers like "Acrobat Reader 9"; if you don't want that and require at least one dot, simply use a `+` instead of a `*`: `/\d+(?:\.\d+)+/`

Or, you could use a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to make sure the regex never matches within a word like "Dots4You": `/\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b/`

Comment: thank you! Could you explain what '/\d+(?:\.\d+)*/' means?

I look at it and I just see gibberish, lol.

Comment: No problem. Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info for a great regex tutorial.

Comment: @Czarek: Um, where? Ah, I've seen the comment in your answer. So what about version numbers without a dot in them?

Comment: We could set priority, first try to match version with a dot, then if there are still 2 possible versions with only 1 digit - take the last.